# Ionic Google maps native plugin language and region change

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have [Google maps plugin for Ionic Native](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps) setup on my app, but I want to change the map language and region.

On the web (JS API) it's done by the script url itself, for example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_key&callback=initMap&region=sa&language=ar

Is there a way to change it in the ionic google maps plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they use system language so there is no way to change it , maybe your app can also use the use system language https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/11/20/migrate-from-cordova-globalization-plugin.html